# Reason: Bad credentials. Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Я только начинаю изучать Spring Security и у меня возникла небольшая проблема, связаная с входом в приложение. Когда я не использую passwordEncoder, вход всегда происходит, но когда я использую passwordEncoder, каждый раз выводится ошибка Reason: Bad credentials. Может быть кто-нибудь знает, в чём может быть проблема.
SecurityConfig.java:

```
package ru.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        super.configure(httpSecurity);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user")).roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user")).roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

}
```

SecurityInit.java

```
package ru.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityInit extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Comment: Откуда конфигурация должна знать про использование хеширования паролей? Бин `passwordEncoder` может использоваться для чего-то другого. В конфигурации должно быть `auth .inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).withUser...`

Comment: Да, все, теперь все работает. Я думал, что достаточно одного passwordEncoder в password. Спасибо вам)